# Low current, +- 20V supply from 5V

Tags: power-supply, low-power, dual-supply

For my application I need +20V and -20V, at a low current, 10mA but probably 1mA might be good enough - difficult to say until I try.

I start with 5V provided by a common USB power supply. I have read of some circuits that can do the +-20V with just a handful of components and no inductors; I would prefer something small that I can integrate on my own PCB along with other circuits instead of a (bulky) external module.

Comment: If you have read of some circuits doing what you want then you should tell us about them and what properties you don't like at them.

Comment: Non inductor circuits will need a capacitive ladder multiplier. Using standard diodes you will need 5+ stages for +20 and -20V. Physical parts count is FAR higher than using inductors. Inductor based circuits are widely available. | Many ideas [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=circuit+5V+to+20V+boost+converter&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwim1_WF2qn2AhUIX2wGHWh8A9cQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=circuit+5V+to+20V+boost+converter&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoHCCMQ7wMQJ1D4A1i6KWDJLWgAcAB4AIABigKIAdcXkgEGMC4xNS4ymAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=bJQgYqbxAYi-seMP6PiNuA0&bih=823&biw=1461&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839)

Comment: ... (Google image search) || BUT a commercial product like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000077783578.html) - EXAMPLE ONLY (much smaller available) will be cheaper and easier.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are thinking of a charge pump, such as a Cockroft-Walton generator.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator

With only 5 V to work with, it will take several stages to build up to 23-25 V, and then regulate down to 20 V.  Linear Tech and Maxim make switched-capacitor charge pump chips, but I don't think they go up to 20 V.

Does the +/-20 V output need to be a precise/regulated value?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be regulated, +-10% is plenty enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to change from 20V to either 18V or 24V there are a lot of really cheap off the shelf isolated DC-DC converter modules out there for like $2~$3 that will take 5V and turn it into either isolated 18V or 24V.  Using two modules you can generate ±18V or ±24V.

Some examples include...

[PDSE1-S5-S24-S](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cui-inc/PDSE1-S5-S24-S/10229830), $2.14, 5V to 24V isolated, 1W
[AM1SS-0524SJZ](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/aimtec/AM1SS-0524SJZ/12456155), $1.97, 5V to 24V isolated, 1W
[RO-0524S/P](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/recom-power/RO-0524S-P/2314957) $7.41, 5V to 24V isolated, 1W

Comment: Wow these are isolated? It would make the whole thing very easy. Any idea why the last one cost so much more than the others even if it seems to have about the same specs?

Comment: @AlessioSangalli Other than being from a different vendor, there doesn't seem to be much reason for the price difference.